# How to pass unsafe pointer to FileStream in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, marshalling, video-capture

I am trying to write images acquired from a webcam to a file via FileStream in C#.  They are 16-bit monochrome so I cannot just write out the Bitmap object.  I am using Marshal.Copy() in order to work around this as follows:

```
        unsafe private void RecordingFrame()
    {
        Bitmap bm16;
        BitmapData bmd;
        Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, UInt16> currentFrame;
        const int ORIGIN_X = 0;
        const int ORIGIN_Y = 0;

        // get image here and put it in bm16...

        bmd = bm16.LockBits(new Rectangle(ORIGIN_X, ORIGIN_Y, bm16.Width, bm16.Height), 
                            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bm16.PixelFormat);

        var length = bmd.Stride * bmd.Height;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        Marshal.Copy(bmd.Scan0, bytes, 0, length);

        fsVideoWriter.Write(bytes, 0, length);
        bm16.UnlockBits(bmd);
    }
```

Is this the best way to accomplish this?  I wanted to simply pass the BitmapData's Scan0 member as a pointer to FileStream but I couldn't figure out how to do this so I copied the data into a byte buffer.  This reduces performance slightly so if I can improve it to achieve a higher frame rate I'd like to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an UnmanagedMemoryStream from bmd.Scan0 and then call CopyTo(fsVideoWriter).  But I'm not sure if this would be any faster than what you have now.

Comment: I can certainly try it, but the goal I had was to find a way to simply pass the bmd.Scan0 directly to a file stream.  Would that be faster as it avoids an additional copy?  I'll look into the UnmanagedMemoryStream anyway because perhaps I can use that for caching multiple frames to write out to disk in one go.

Comment: There is no way I know of to pass an IntPtr directly to a FileStream method.  If you don't want to use an UnmanagedMemoryStream (which should effectively accomplish the same thing) you could consider using the Win32 File I/O routines instead to write the file (i.e. PInvoke to CreateFile/WriteFile/CloseHandle.)

Comment: FileStream.Write() takes a byte[] parameter, which sucks because I need it to take ushort*.  I looked at UnmanagedMemoryStream, but I'm not sure it is any better than what I am doing above because it still requires a copy.

Comment: I am going to try this guy's library which wraps Win32 File I/O.  The included tests ran pretty fast.  http://designingefficientsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/efficient-file-io-from-csharp/

Comment: Just FYI, I don't think using UnmanagedMemoryStream would require you to copy the buffer.

Comment: So if I were to pass bmd.Scan0 to it it wouldn't copy the data an extra time?  When I first saw your message, I thought CopyTo() was similar to Marshal.Copy(), but it appears to me now that it is replacing the call to fsVideoWriter.Write().  Is this correct?